Cannot Access Laravel Public Folder in Live Ubuntu Server
Problem:
I can't access all file in public folder, but when i'm in index.php there is no problem.



I've just provide my index.php screenshot, there is some asset(image,css,js) that's not loaded, when i inspect element, i get 404 error. Same result when, i'm manually write url in browser, I've already checked in server, the file is exists.
This problem only happens in live server, when in development environment this problem isn't happening. All file is same, cause i'm just cloning it from local to my live server
Server and project description:

Ubuntu 22
PHP 8
Node JS 18
NPM 10
I'm using laravel 11

Some parts on my .env in live server:
APP_NAME="Everbright Web Integrated"
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64:xxx
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC
APP_URL=https://192.168.8.210:443

Things already do:

php artisan storage:link -> result fail
set permission in public folder to 777 -> result fail
manually check file is exists -> result fail
change env to productionn -> result fail

I'm expecting there is no 404 error when access file in public folder
Apache directives in /etc/apache2/sites-available/xxx.conf that apply to this virtual server
DocumentRoot /home/public_html/ewi/public
ServerAdmin xxx
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/xxx
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/xxx
<Directory /home/public_html/ewi>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/demo-error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/demo-access.log combined


Here my routes file :
<?php          
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;          
Route::get('/', function () {         if (Auth::check()) {             return view('home', ['kdSupp' => Auth::user()->kdsupp]);         } else {             return view('welcome');         }     });          
Auth::routes();          
Route::get('/list-supp', [App\Http\Controllers\WebRequestController::class, 'listSupplier']);          
Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');     

// Surat Jalan     
Route::get('/surat-jalan/upload', [App\Http\Controllers\SuratJalanController::class, 'index']);     
Route::get('/surat-jalan/view', [App\Http\Controllers\SuratJalanController::class, 'lihatSuratJalan']);     
Route::get('/surat-jalan/detail/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\SuratJalanController::class, 'lihatDetailSuratJalan']);     
Route::post('/surat-jalan/upload', [App\Http\Controllers\SuratJalanController::class, 'importExcel']);     
Route::patch('/surat-jalan/ubah', [App\Http\Controllers\SuratJalanController::class, 'ubahSuratJalan']);     
Route::patch('/surat-jalan/ubah-item', [App\Http\Controllers\SuratJalanController::class, 'ubahItemSuratJalan']);     
Route::delete('/surat-jalan/hapus', [App\Http\Controllers\SuratJalanController::class, 'hapusSuratJalan']);     
Route::delete('/surat-jalan/hapus-item', [App\Http\Controllers\SuratJalanController::class, 'hapusItemSuratJalan']);     
// End Surat Jalan          

//Invoice     
Route::get('/invoice/upload', [App\Http\Controllers\InvoiceController::class, 'index']);     
Route::get('/invoice/view', [App\Http\Controllers\InvoiceController::class, 'lihatInvoice']);     
Route::get('/invoice/detail/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\InvoiceController::class, 'lihatDetailInvoice']);     
Route::post('/invoice/upload', [App\Http\Controllers\InvoiceController::class, 'importExcel']);     
Route::patch('/invoice/ubah', [App\Http\Controllers\InvoiceController::class, 'ubahInvoice']);     
Route::patch('/invoice/ubah-harga', [App\Http\Controllers\InvoiceController::class, 'ubahHarga']);     
Route::delete('/invoice/hapus', [App\Http\Controllers\InvoiceController::class, 'hapusInvoice']);     
Route::delete('/invoice/hapus-sj', [App\Http\Controllers\InvoiceController::class, 'hapusSuratJalan']);     
//End Invoice

//Faktur Pajak     
Route::get('/faktur-pajak/upload', [App\Http\Controllers\FakturPajakController::class, 'index']);     
Route::get('/faktur-pajak/view', [App\Http\Controllers\FakturPajakController::class, 'lihatFakturPajak']);     
Route::get('/faktur-pajak/detail/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\FakturPajakController::class, 'lihatDetailFakturPajak']);     
Route::post('/faktur-pajak/upload', [App\Http\Controllers\FakturPajakController::class, 'importExcel']);     
Route::patch('/faktur-pajak/ubah', [App\Http\Controllers\FakturPajakController::class, 'ubahFP']);     
Route::patch('/faktur-pajak/ubah-invoice', [App\Http\Controllers\FakturPajakController::class, 'ubahInvoice']);     
Route::delete('/faktur-pajak/hapus', [App\Http\Controllers\FakturPajakController::class, 'hapusFP']);     
Route::delete('/faktur-pajak/hapus-invoice', [App\Http\Controllers\FakturPajakController::class, 'hapusInvoice']);     
//End Faktur Pajak          

Route::post('/upload-excel', [App\Http\Controllers\UploadController::class, 'prosesUpload']);     // Download Route     Route::get('download/template/{filename}', function ($filename) {         // Check if file exists in app/storage/file folder         $file_path = storage_path() . '/file/' . $filename;         if (file_exists($file_path)) {             // Send Download             return Response::download($file_path, $filename, [                 'Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_path)             ]);         } else {             // Error             exit('Requested file does not exist on our server!');         }     })         ->where('filename', '[A-Za-z0-9\-\_\.]+');     


try removing public from the URL

already tried too but same result, in that inspect element screenshot (3rd error, logo.png), the request url is without public

I think there's something off with the APP_URL=https://192.168.8.210:443. If SSL isn't set up for the app, changing https to http might do the trick.

yes, there is no ssl set up, but i've just tested to changing https to http, but nothing happens, still same like before

it is an interesting problem! did you try to remove the port 443 definition in APP_URL in .env? or maybe there is a problem in your routes file that overrides the public path!

thanks for the suggestion, but i've already tried to remove the port, but still same, already stuck here for couple days and still not find the solution in SO. let me, show some routes file

Are you sure this problem is in any way related to PHP, Laravel, or Webmin? Is the public folder served through PHP in any way?

From the content of your question, PHP access is OK, but static assets like logo.png are not.  If that is correct, your routes are not relevant - Laravel and .htaccess do not affect static files.  Ignore PHP and Laravel for now, focus on a single file like logo.png.  Make a request to http:///logo.png, and check your Apache logs.  Are you sure your vhost config is effective when using the IP address, not a hostname?

I'm using webmin to host my laravel project, and i'm sure it's served through PHP, cause in dev environment, this problem is not happening @NicoHaase

PHP/Laravel does NOT serve static files, like the ones in your public folder. Can you explain what you mean by "manually check file is exists -> result fail"?

<Directory /home/public_html/ewi> shouldn't that be the same as your DocumentRoot directory?

@krisgjika just want to be clear in that public folder the file is exists, so the problem is not because the file is missing

@brombeer just same results,  if i add /public in directory

Finally found the solution of this problem. I just delete this line in apache conf file
   # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

I don't know what that line mean, i just follow other SO solution, but realize something strange, so i delete that line and all is solved

Enable mod_rewrite Module:
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo systemctl restart apache2

Check Apache User:
Open the Apache configuration file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf or /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.
change the ownership of the public directory to www-data
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/public_html/ewi/public

Clear Cache
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan view:cache

